# Flexbox in combination with IE10: doesn't work when I wrap the children in a div and a href container

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

In IE10, when I wrap the children in a div and a href container, the children are displayed in a column instead of a row. All other browsers work. I have no idea what to do about this. Can someone shine some light on this?

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">
      <a class="item_container1">
       <div class="item_container2">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200">
       </div>
      </a>
      <a class="item_container1">
       <div class="item_container2">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200">
       </div>
      </a>
      <a class="item_container1">
       <div class="item_container2">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200">
       </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #container {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;

      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/LeMiguel72/pen/wWGEmq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The a elements need to be displayed as block.

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```